# While installing redbox plugin to rails why does it say Plugin not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

When I try to install redbox plugin although everything gets installed, a last line says plugin not found. Why is that ?

```
script/plugin install http://svn2.cvsdude.com/craigambrose/plugins/redbox
+ ./README
+ ./Rakefile
+ ./images/redbox_spinner.gif
+ ./init.rb
+ ./install.rb
+ ./javascripts/redbox.js
+ ./lib/redbox.rb
+ ./lib/redbox_helper.rb
+ ./stylesheets/redbox.css
+ ./tasks/redbox_tasks.rake
+ ./test/redbox_test.rb
Plugin not found: ["http://svn2.cvsdude.com/craigambrose/plugins/redbox"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths inside `vendor/plugins/redbox/install.rb` appear to be wrong:

```
plugins_dir = File.expand_path(".")
redbox_dir = File.join(plugins_dir, 'redbox')
root_dir = File.join(redbox_dir, '..', '..', '..')

File.copy File.join(redbox_dir, 'javascripts', 'redbox.js'), File.join(root_dir, 'public', 'javascripts', 'redbox.js')
File.copy File.join(redbox_dir, 'stylesheets', 'redbox.css'), File.join(root_dir, 'public', 'stylesheets', 'redbox.css')
File.copy File.join(redbox_dir, 'images', 'redbox_spinner.gif'), File.join(root_dir, 'public', 'images', 'redbox_spinner.gif')
```

The `redbox_dir` path isn't accounting for the `vendor/plugins` path components.  But you can complete the installation yourself by manually copying the three files listed above from the `vendor/plugins/redbox` directory to the appropriate subdirectories beneath your app's `public` directory.

Comment: Is this the correct approach ? I mean do I need to do this with all plugins or is this a problem with redbox ?

Comment: It's only a problem with redbox, but in general, any time you see "Plugin not found", check the plugin's install.rb file to see if you can determine the "real" error.